# How to pass custom values for fb_share with box count? (description inside)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, facebook

I need to enable facebook sharing with box count to a website. I'm using the following code,

```
<div id="fbShare">
    <a name="fb_share" type="button_count" expr:share_url="data:post.url" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share</a>
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

I got this from http://developers.facebook.com. My site content are all dynamic, when I click the share button it takes the default meta title and meta description and some random images.

But I need to pass my own title, description and image. I changed the meta values on page load but still it takes the default. Then I saw open graph, so I've also given the og:title, og:descrip... etc., But nothing works.

Finally I've tried the following code,

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[url]=http://example.com/View?Id=xxxx&p[images][0]=http://example.com/Images/logo.jpg&p[title]=Title&p[summary]=page summary">Share on Facebook</a>
```

the problem is it doesn't show the count.

Somebody please say me how to achieve this fb_sahre with box count and pass values dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to do it.

I am generating the following metatags in the `<head>` section:

```
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="524237027611839"/>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="662177149"/ >
    <meta property="og:title" content='Rustic basket'/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Afula: Rustic basket "/ >
    <meta property="og:url" content='http://en.2send.co.il/product/11' />
    <meta property="og:image" content='http://en.2send.co.il/Files/Products/11_2_17.jpg'/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="This bouquet expressing appropriate for thanks, apologies and appreciation."/>
```

**Facebook script:**

```
<body>
<script>

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=524237027611839";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));       

    </script>
```

**The following div is replaced by the sharing box:**

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href='http://2send.co.il/product/11' data-send="true" data-show-faces="true" data-width="75" data-show-faces="false" data-layout="box_count">
                    </div>
```

You can see the full example here: http://en.2send.co.il/product/11